# Can someone help me with parallel processing for Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am searching for a possible solution to read and trigger data (in my case waveform data) parallel.

I have a list (wfpathlist), just a list containing strings with given paths to the files:

```
for fn in wfpathlist:
    st = readWaveform(fn, bpfreq=[5.,30.])
    coinc = CoincidenceTimes(st)
    triggerlist += coinc.getCoincTimes()
    events += cutWithList(wfpath=fn, trigg=coinc.getCoincTimes(), 
    station=self.getStation())
```

With readWaveform just being a short function to read and filter the data:

```
def readWaveform(wfpath, bpfreq=[5., 30.]):
    st = read(wfpath)
    st.filter('bandpass', freqmin=bpfreq[0], freqmax=bpfreq[1])
    return st
```

Is there a easy solution for somebody with just a very basic understanding of programming to let this for-loop run parallel?

Thanks alot,

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your for-loop in a function, and call this function with the multiprocessing.Pool() object.
This will parallelize the execution of your loop and should add a nice speedup.

Example :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(fn): 
    st = readWaveform(fn, bpfreq=[5.,30.])
    coinc = CoincidenceTimes(st)
    triggerlist += coinc.getCoincTimes()
    events += cutWithList(wfpath=fn, trigg=coinc.getCoincTimes(), 
    station=self.getStation())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4) # if you have 4 cores in your processor
    p.map(func, wfpathlist)
```

source : https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Note that some python-implemented function already use multiprocessing (common in numpy), so you should check your processor activity when your script is running before implementing this solution.

EDIT : my bad, you should send directly your list to pool. I corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried your solution, but am getting a problem, since my list "wfpathlist" looks like this: ['/data/SDS/2014/1A/ZV??/?H?.D/*.364',
 '/data/SDS/2014/1A/ZV??/?H?.D/*.365',
 '/data/SDS/2015/1A/ZV??/?H?.D/*.001',
 '/data/SDS/2015/1A/ZV??/?H?.D/*.002']

I am getting this error: 
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.

Comment: Okay, he begins to work. But after a while i get the following error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'triggerlist' referenced before assignment.


I assigned triggerlist before the function as triggerlist=[]

Comment: Python has a Global Interpreter Lock that forbid to start several Threads at the same time (to avoid memory conflicts and so). If you want to parallelize, each process has its own memory space and they don't communicate **at all** between processes.
The simpler way is to modify your implementation so that every step of your for-loop is independant and doesn't need access to variables in another process.
If it is not possible, you can communicate between processes with shared array (multiprocessing.Array) or Pipes (multiprocessing.Pipe) but you have to be careful about thread-safety.

Comment: I dont think I can make every step independant. In that case, I would first have to read the waveforms of every event. But then I get a memory error. That was the reason I use a for-loop, to read single waveforms, then trigger and cut small parts out of it, then read the next one.

Comment: For example in your case maybe you can return a list of all the results you want to have in each loop, for instance [st,coinc,triggerlist,events,station] and then sort your data in post-treatement. In fact here your pool won't get you anything because there is no return in your function.

Comment: Okay, I will try to get it working, so that my output at the end ist correct. Thanks alot for your help, it begins working, reading seems to work, so I think the beginning is done.

Thank you, and have a nice day :)

Comment: you're welcome :) Please set the question to solved and share your corrected code if possible.